# Instalar aplicação C# com banco SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Fiz um programa C# de cadastros simples utilizando banco de dados SQL Server 2008.

Quando fui instalar em outro computador, me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Isto se deve ao fato de que o servidor no qual estou tentando instalar a aplicação é diferente do qual eu usei para criá-la, portanto a instância de conexão fica diferente. O que devo fazer para conseguir instalar meu programa em outros computadores?

Comment: Você possui o Sql Server instalados nos outros computadores?

Comment: @Randrade possuo sim!

Comment: O SQL Server está na mesma maquina que o aplicativo?

Comment: @Randrade positivo!

Comment: Você irá instalar na máquina local ou em um servidor? Como está definindo a conexão atualmente?

Comment: Vou instalar na máquina local. A string de conexão está assim: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\data\Sistema.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Answer (score 1):

Nas melhores práticas de dev com banco de dados cliente-servidor, você deve armazenar a string de conexão dentro do arquivo Web.config ou App.config. 
Isso porque, quando você instalar a aplicação em uma segunda estação de trabalho, você pode alterar essa configuração editando o arquivo para apontar para o banco de dados no servidor.

Provavelmente se você já está fazendo isso, basta apenas alterar esta string de conexão (connetionString) para o computador onde fica o BD.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará de uma forma para configurar a connectionstring da sua conexão. A forma de configuração depende de qual componente você usou para fazer a conexão com o bando de dados. Além de também ser necessário liberar as portas do sql server no firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Você fez uma aplicação que em cada computador que for instalado vai precisar conectar em um sql server local?

Se sim a melhor opção seria você criar uma opção pro usuário mapear o banco de dados no primeiro acesso.

Comment: Pensei nisso também, mas é possível fazer isto mesmo que eu esteja copiando o arquivo .mdf para a máquina que irei instalar a aplicação? Porque o banco já está criado e não gostaria de ter que recriá-lo toda vez que for instalar em um computador diferente.